# Spotlight and Alfred can't find alias to Emacs.app

Tags: spotlight, macos, alfred

I installed Emacs.app with Homebrew, and used `brew linkapps` to create an alias in my `/Applications` directory.

Since I updated to OS X Mavericks yesterday, Spotlight and Alfred can no longer see this alias.

Since discovering the problem, I've tried reindexing my MacBook as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32880/spotlight-and-alfred-cant-find-photo-booth), as well as reinstalling Emacs and restarting the machine.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/3182-autocompletion-does-not-work-on-symlinks-aliases/?p=18471).

I needed to add the Homebrew cellar path to the list of paths under *Features | Default Results | Search Scope*, and then Alfred recursively scanned it and found Emacs.

On my Mac the path was `/usr/local/Cellar`.

And there was great rejoicing!

Comment: on a apple silicon Mac Book Pro as of 2021-12-13 my path was `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`

Answer (score 9):

For some reason, including `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` (the path to Homebrew's Cellar on Apple Silicon devices) in Alfred's **Search Scope** doesn't work, at least for Emacs.

But I found a more generic solution that should work for any application. The trick is to create an alias in `/Applications` to the application's `.app` dir/bundle, and then to tell Alfred to include macOS aliases in search results.

I use Homebrew-installed Emacs as an example below because generalizing the instructions would make the language awkward. Extending the example ought to be trivial.

First, create a macOS alias (not a symlink):

- In **Finder**, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto-complete to enter the path of the directory containing "Emacs.app" (In my case, this is currently `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-27.2-mac-8.3`)
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new **Finder** window, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to go to `/Applications`
- Create the alias by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd> dragging "Emacs.app" from the homebrew window to the `/Applications` window.

Now, let's make Alfred include macOS aliases in search results:

- Open Alfred's preferences (alfred 4.7), navigate to **Features** > **Default Results** click **Advanced...**. A popup window will open that allows you to add file types that will be shown in search results.
- Drag the `Emacs.app` alias from the **Finder** `/Applications` window to the popup window. The new entry should read `com.apple.alias-file  |  alias`
- Close the popup and try searching for 'emacs'. The result list should include the "Emacs.app" alias.

The alias will fail at every update that changes the versioned path to the app in the Cellar, which happens to be `emacs-27.2-mac-8.3` at writing. The correct solution to the underlying problem is to fix Alfred so it picks up applications installed to `/opt`. A hacky alternative might be to hook into `homebrew` and recreate the alias when needed.

I'll probably manually recreate the alias each time it breaks so that the breakage can serve as a reminder to check for an upstream fix to the underlying problem.

Comment: It is necessary to make a Mac 'alias' and not a UNIX symbolic link. Both are labelled with "Kind: alias" in Finder. But they are different types apparently. The UNIX symbolic link is interpreted as a link to a directory (the `.app` file can be opened like a directory). Whereas the Mac alias interprets it as a link to an actual app.

Answer (score 1):

I actually came across this back in March with the release of Alfred 2 and documented my solution here: http://blog.victorquinn.com/alfred-2-and-emacs

Perhaps that'll help you.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone and not fully rely on off-site information (which may disappear, similar to the first link in the page you are referring to).

Comment: FYI: victorquinn.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate expired on 21 July 2016 at 16:03.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred Preference >> Features >> Default Results >> Search Scope
in Search Scope: 
Finder Folder Clicked and Just Drag and Drop! (not emacs.app but The parents Folder) 
[image]

Just Drag and Drop!!!